# Multiple attacks in a round (iterative attacks)

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, dnd-3e

In what order do iterative attacks resolve? Right after the character who has initiative has resolved his first attack (attack with highest BAB), or do the other characters and npc's resolve their first attack before the iterative attacks?

Example: Ser Fisty McBeef-Punch is a 6th level fighter and has a BAB of +6/+1. He is currently fighting 2 Gnolls, also with a BAB of +6/+1. By some twist of fates Ser Fisty rolls highest on initiative and proceeds to carve a gash in Gnoll#1's stomach with his +6 bab attack. Does Ser Fisty then get his +1 attack before the Gnolls get their +6 attack, or do the Gnolls strike back first and so on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Iterative attacks require a full-attack
2. A full-attack is a full-round action (replaces your move and standard actions)
3. Move, standard, and full-round actions take place on your turn
4. Generally, actions are not interrupted by other things

Thus, you take a full-round action to full-attack. This allows you to use your iteratives, so you make two attacks, one at +6 and another at +1. Assuming you have no swift actions you wish to use, this ends your turn, and now the gnoll goes (and can potentially full-attack and get his own two attacks, one at +6 and the other at +1).

Comment: Thanks alot man :) This has been a mystery in my gaming group for years :)

Comment: @SerFistyMcBeef-Punch Depending on how long this has been a mystery, this may not have always been the correct answer to that mystery. Some of the early versions of D&D did have you take your first strike, then others go, then back to you for your iteratives.

Comment: The D&D group I used to be with handled it as everyone having their first attack, then everyone's second attack, and so on. I actually hadn't realized that people did it differently.